# Seg Error while erasing from multiset C++

Tags: c++, stl, segmentation-fault, multiset

I don't know whats making this code give an error. It's a simple multiset. No compilation errors, but segmentation fault on the machine while executing.

g++ version : 4.8.2

Machine : Ubuntu 14.04

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

struct compare
{
    bool operator() (int lhs, int rhs) { return lhs < rhs; }
};
typedef multiset < int, compare >  mi;

mi sett;

int main(void)
{
    sett.insert(5);
    sett.insert(5);
    sett.erase(*sett.begin());
    sett.erase(*sett.rbegin());
    printf("Done\n");
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use a debugger like GDB or Valgrind ?

Comment: First call to sett.insert(5); would have erased all "5" values in the multiset. So after the first call to sett.insert(5); the mutliset has become empty and the second erase call will cause a crash.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your first `erase` effectively emptied your `multiset`.

From [`std::multiset::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/erase) (emphasis mine)

> Removes specified elements from the container.
>   1) Removes the element at pos.
>   2) Removes the elements in the range [first; last), which must be a valid range in *this.
>   3) **Removes all elements with the key value key.**
>   References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other references and iterators are not affected.
>   The iterator pos must be valid and dereferenceable. Thus the end() iterator (which is valid, but is not dereferencable) cannot be used as a value for pos.

Therefore the second time you are trying to `erase` you are trying to dereference `std::multiset::end`, which is what is returned by `sett.rbegin()` for the empty `multiset`

Comment: thanks :), is there a way to delete only the pointer I want to delete?

Comment: Yes you could have said `sett.erase(sett.begin())` and this would have used [overload `(1)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/erase) which just erases that specific element, because you are passing an iterator, not a specific value.

Answer (score 3):

You are erasing not an iterator, you are erasing a value.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/erase

You use function 3. You remove *all* values with value 5. So, after the first erase, your set is empty.